# How to use other Usercontrol properties

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, user-controls

how can i use other `usercontrol` properties let say, i create a `listBox` in that `usercontrol`. Then i want to `manupulate` that list box from main user control.Both of them different `usercontrol`.

so far, i try to do like this:

```
public VwLog refFromLog { get; set; }
```

.

```
VwLog log = (VwLog)this.refFromLog; 
test = new Simple(log.listBox.Items);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make events, methods, and properties for the ListBox in the usercontrol that contains the ListBox. For example, make a listboxadd method in UserControl that calls listbox.add. Then you can access these public events, methods, and properties from a main usercontrol2 or form that contains the first usercontrol.